# CustomValidator to implement IsRequired on Ajax AutoCompleteExtender

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to implement an `IsRequired` attribute on our own lookup control (actually a wrapper containing an Ajax `AutoCompleteExtender` and one `CustomValidator`). As you know, implementing proper validation for a lookup control doesn't just involve checking is the control is not empty, the entry has to actually exist in the lookup prediction list.

I'm doing this with the following `ClientValidationFunction` wired to the `CustomValidator`:

```
function ValidateLookup(sender, args) {
var isValidEntry = $("#" + sender.controltovalidate)
                    .parent()
                    .children()
                    .filter("input:first")
                    .attr('ValidEntry') == args.Value;

if (isValidEntry)
    args.IsValid = true;
else {
    var acEntries = $("#" + sender.controltovalidate)
                    .parent()
                    .find("li[innerText=" + args.Value + "]");
    args.IsValid = acEntries.length > 0;
    if (args.IsValid)
        $("#" + sender.controltovalidate)
        .parent()
        .children()
        .filter("input:first")
        .attr('ValidEntry', args.Value);
}
```

}

I'm exploiting how the AutoCompleteExtender renders to check the entry, I know there's a textbox for your entry, a hidden that holds the last selected value (doesn't get populated till validation passes though) and one unordered list(ul) that holds the lookup predictions.

Right now this works, but I don't know if anyone has an idea of how to make it look less like a hack. The current issue is that validating the current entry against the list of predictions only works when validation is invoked by the control (as the ul is populated and available/floating below the autocomplete box). When the page invokes the validation the ul is not there, that's why I added that "if the current entry is the same as the last valid entry don't check anything else".

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end this was a pretty good approach, plus some minor modifications. Maybe this will be of use to someone trying to implement this... as it's a very known issue that validation fires BEFORE whatever js code you set on the extender's `OnClientItemSelected`.

1) I added a SelectedText hidden to keep track of the last valid text entered in the autocomplete. This field gets populated via OnClientItemSelected. This covers validation during postbacks and page-level validation.

2) I modified the the ValidateLookup function hooked to the CustomValidator:

```
function ValidateLookup(sender, args) {
var selectedText = $("#" + sender.controltovalidate)
                    .parent()
                    .children()
                    .filter("[id$=_selectedText]").val();
var isValidEntry = args.Value != "" && selectedText == args.Value;

if (isValidEntry)
    args.IsValid = true;
else {
    var acEntries = $("#" + sender.controltovalidate)
                        .parent()
                        .children()
                        .filter(function() {
                            return this.innerText == args.Value;
                        });
    args.IsValid = acEntries.length > 0;
}
}
```

The filter function that I'm using to scan the autocomplete box is just there to deal with characters that usually need escaping (Entries in the autocomplete with backslashes, apostrophes, etc).